# Caching REST XML Responses

Tags: nginx, caching, reverse-proxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have to support a legacy system which uses REST API but POST only. The body contains XML data which needs to parsed at the server to understand the resource.

As the legacy application can't be changed we can't add caching to it i.e Redis. So to speed things up I am thinking of putting a reverse proxy cache such as Varnish between the load balancer and web server. But that would require parsing of the request body to look at the XML paths.

Are there any third party open source modules which do this and won't require much re-writing.

Varnish modules
Nginx + Lua + XML parsing

The last option would be to write an application that would act as a cache (custom code with Redis) and query would be passed to the web server if there is a miss.

Comment: Parsing the POST response body or request body?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do caching using Nginx proxy_cache which saves the key in file on disk and not in RAM. Example nginx.conf

```
    proxy_cache_key        $http_x_custom_header;
    proxy_cache_revalidate off;
    proxy_cache_methods    POST;
    proxy_cache_valid      200 1m;
```

The whole HTTP POST response body gets cached in the proxy_cache.